# Is maven-qunit-plugin dead or do I not know how to use it?

Tags: javascript, maven, automation, qunit

I feel ridiculous having to ask this, but I can't tell if maven-qunit-plugin is dead and unusable or if I just can't get it to work.

Project URL:
http://code.google.com/p/qunit-maven-plugin/

maven-qunit-plugin looks to be the best documented of the qunit-maven connectors. I have gotten http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs-qunit-runner/ to run, but it doesn't support multiple folders so I have disqualified it.

I can't get maven-qunit-plugin to install. I have tried repositories from moyrax and from atlassian and they are both not found. I also tried downloading the source and building the plugin myself but it has errors I don't understand that refer to moyrax URLs "Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.moyrax.qunit:dev:pom:1.2.4 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)"

Do I need to give up on this plugin? Is it a dead project, or has someone seen where it moved to?

Comment: I guess I'm assuming it's dead at this point... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a dead project, based on the problems I had and the lack of response.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the last change committed was in Nov. of 2010:

http://code.google.com/p/qunit-maven-plugin/source/list